# Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info

Tags: python, pip

Opa galera, blz?? 
Estava tentando rodar o comando `pip install MySQL-python` e o console me retornou esse erro:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/65/jkyt0ypj7mj7686wbsw_p1_m0000gn/T/pip-install-cis2n2x_/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/65/jkyt0ypj7mj7686wbsw_p1_m0000gn/T/pip-install-cis2n2x_/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
     cwd: /private/var/folders/65/jkyt0ypj7mj7686wbsw_p1_m0000gn/T/pip-install-cis2n2x_/MySQL-python/
Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/65/jkyt0ypj7mj7686wbsw_p1_m0000gn/T/pip-install-cis2n2x_/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    from setup_posix import get_config
  File "/private/var/folders/65/jkyt0ypj7mj7686wbsw_p1_m0000gn/T/pip-install-cis2n2x_/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py 
egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Alguém sabe como me ajudar ? Já tentei as seguintes soluções:

1. `pip install -U setuptools`
2. `brew reinstall python`
3. `sudo pip install MySQL-python`

E nada funciona..
Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opa, então cara o erro que está retornando aí que merece atenção é o seguinte:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

E pode existir alguns motivos para isso.
O mais provavel seria que o no Python 3, o '[ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)' foi renomeado para '[configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)' pelo [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Então, parece que o pacote que está tentando instalar não é compatível com o Python 3, então temos uma alternativa:

Você pode usar o pacote [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) como alternativa por ser uma "versão" do `MySQL-python` com suporte a Python 3. Então basta apenas baixar esse pacote com:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```